# How to prove contour integral of product is equal to product of contour integrals

Tags: contour-integration

Let $f,g$ be analytic on some domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$. By Cauchy's formula, we have
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\partial\Omega}
\frac{f(z) \, g(z)}{z - z_0}
\, dz
= 
f(z_0) \, g(z_0)
= 
-\frac{1}{4\pi^2} 
\oint_{\partial\Omega}
\frac{f(u)}{u - z_0}
\, du
\, 
\oint_{\partial\Omega}
\frac{g(v)}{v - z_0}
\, dv
.
$$
Is there a way how I can get from the first expression to the last without the intermediate step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus#The_homomorphism_property). The main tool of the proof is the so-called *first resolvent formula*
$$
\frac{1}{(z-z_0) \, (w - z_0)}
=
\frac{1}{w-z} \, \left(\frac{1}{z - z_0} - \frac{1}{w - z_0}\right)
.
$$
To see how this is useful, introduce another contour $\partial \Omega'$ and write
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\partial\Omega} \frac{f(z) \, g(z)}{z - z_0} \, dz
&=
-\frac{1}{4\pi^2} \oint_{\partial\Omega} \frac{f(z)}{z - z_0} \oint_{\partial\Omega'} \frac{g(w)}{w-z} \, dw\, dz
\\&=
-\frac{1}{4\pi^2} \oint_{\partial\Omega} \oint_{\partial\Omega'} f(z) \, g(w) \, \frac{1}{(z-z_0)\,(w-z)} \, dw\, dz
.
\end{align}
This last fraction is precisely the first term on the right-hand side of the resolvent formula, and the second term can be added if we pick $\Omega' \supset \Omega$  because then
$$
\oint_{\partial\Omega} \oint_{\partial\Omega'} \frac{f(z) \, g(w) }{(w-z_0)\,(w-z)} \, dw \, dz
=
\oint_{\partial\Omega'} \oint_{\partial\Omega} \frac{f(z) \, g(w)}{(w-z_0)\,(w-z)} \, dz \, dw
= 
0
$$
by Fubini's theorem (note that the integration domain as well as the integrand are bounded) and Cauchy's theorem (the integrand is analytic for $z \in \Omega \subset \Omega'$). Therefore, 
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\partial\Omega} \frac{f(z) \, g(z)}{z - z_0} \, dz
=
-\frac{1}{4\pi^2} \oint_{\partial\Omega} \oint_{\partial\Omega'} \frac{f(z) \, g(w)}{(z - z_0) \, (w-z_0)} \, dw\, dz
.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. If I am guessing correctly what you have in mind, then it is a proof which is local in the sense that it only involves the functions in  neighbourhood of the integration path, i.e. a proof that would still work if $f$ and $g$ are not analytic on all of $\Omega$. But then the formula does not hold any more, consider e.g. $z_0=0$, $f(z)=1/z$, $g(z)=z$.